# Python dictionary and loop confusion during lookup of dictionary

Tags: python, django, algorithm, numpy, scipy

This result I get from the code below is wrong:

```
[
'199|4|11|GDSPV', 
'199|4|11|GDSPV|199|16|82|GDSPV', 
'199|4|11|GDSPV|199|16|82|GDSPV|205|16|82|GDSPV'
]
```

I wanted a result to be the same as the **fr** list BUT with email replaced with values of dictionary **d**. I am totally lost as to why this doesn't work as expected?

```
fr = [
'7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV',
'7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV',
'13@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV'
]

d= {
'7@comp1.COM': '199',
'8@comp4.COM': '200',
'13@comp1.COM': '205'
}


col_list=[]
line_list=[]

for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    for col in columns:
        if col==columns[0]:
            col_list.append(d[col])
            continue
        col_list.append(col)
        #i = i + 1
    line_list.append("|".join(col_list))
print line_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
line_list=[]
for line in fr:
    cols = line.split('|')
    key = cols[0]
    cols[0]=d[key]
    line_list.append('|'.join(cols))

print line_list
```

Comment: This will throw a `KeyError` exception if `key` is not in `d`.

Comment: if the dictionary doesn't have the user_id, i would like to populate the dictionary with the new email found as key and the integer as the value as the next integer 206, 207 208 etc.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset col_list when you start to process each line.  I.e. put the `col_list=[]` call just before `for col in columns:`

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
# col_list=[] you don't need this
line_list=[]

for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
print line_list
```

Comment: this code gives an error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects` for line `new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+columns[1:]`

Comment: Salam mr. Khalid. How can i add to the dictionary a new email with its respective next integer 206, 207 etc... if found in fr. Also I need to keep track of new email addresses in fr, so I need to append the details of the dict d in a file.

Answer (score 0):

check this ... in sample.py

```
fr = [
'7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV',
'7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV',
'13@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV'
]

d= {
'7@comp1.COM': '199',
'8@comp4.COM': '200',
'13@comp1.COM': '205'
}

col_list=[]
line_list=[]

for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    if d.has_key(columns[0]):
        col_list.append(d[columns[0]])
    else:
        col_list.append(columns[0])
    col_list.extend(columns[1:])
    line_list.append("|".join(col_list))

print line_list
```

output

```
D:\>python sample.py
['199|4|11|GDSPV', '199|4|11|GDSPV|199|16|82|GDSPV', '199|4|11|GDSPV|199|16|82|G
DSPV|205|16|82|GDSPV']
```